# How can I make AutoHotkey script work on Raspberry / alternative?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, script

Is it possible to run AutoHotkey scripts on Raspberry Pi 3 Raspbian OS? If not, is it possible to run .exe on Raspberry?

And if that is not possible either, what programming language(s) are required on Raspberry Pi 3 to:

- start browser
- go to Gmail
- log into my Gmail account
- loop

I wonder if that is possible at all to do with Raspberry Pi 3? Maybe it works with a specific OS? Or there aren't programming languages needed at all for this?

Please tell me how to do it, I'm a big noob, all I can do is writing AutoHotkey / AutoIt scripts.

Comment: Perhaps could you give a chance to xdotool http://theembeddedlab.com/tutorials/simulate-keyboard-mouse-events-xdotool-raspberry-pi/ or actionaz https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQz_t0MzDv0

Comment: Something like the Xautomation package to send keystrokes and click in locations. If you use Chromium and log in with your Gmail you could just set it to boot straight to the Gmail page.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/7/xautomation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoHotKey is a windows scripting language. You cannot run it natively on a Linux operating system. It is technically possible to run it through [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/), but that hardly seems worth the effort, in my opinion.

The official scripting language of the Raspberry Pi is [python](http://python.org), but numerous other options like [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), [perl](https://www.perl.org/), or [php](http://php.net) would work just as well.

Your best bet at this point is to look into learning one of those.

Comment: Thank you for answer! :D Just one more question; which of these supported languages would you recommend me? I'm looking for script languages, something like: Open browser, go to this stack raspberry site, log into my account, and say "thanks for answer" (this was just an example!) :)

Comment: Python combined with its package, selenium, would be your best bet (in my opinion)

Comment: Awesome, I will study that in the week end then, thanks!

Comment: Ummm, do we have a reference for "official scripting language"?  I know it's been acknowledged that it influenced the *official name*, but that seems to be adding a telephone-game-eque twist, esp. considering it's a device which does not come with any OEM installed software!  Beyond that I agree with everything you've said, so this isn't really an objection to much.

Comment: @goldilocks: see point 2 https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#softwareLanguages

Comment: More twisted telephone game!  Unless "recommended for learners" == "official scripting language" ...An honor I guess should be shared with Scratch \O/